# turn on USB charging windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, power-management

I would like to charge a phone via usb to a windows 10 machine, specifically a Lenovo m83 tiny. The ports on the front bezel (pictured) sustain power to the phone, but when plugged into a port on the back, the phone charges for about 5 seconds until the computer shuts off output of power. Is there a way to enable charging on all the ports and not just the two in front?

[computer front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koo9g.jpg)

I have tried tweaking the power management settings for the usb hub drivers in the device manager, unchecking "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power." for all the usb hubs then restarted the computer, but this had no effect. Any other settings to try or is this hardwired?

[device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGLEU.png)

Comment: What is the computer's exact model?

Answer (score 1):

USB was not originally designed for charging devices, but it works pretty well for it.  So I'm not surprised you can't use your back ports to charge your phone.

You may want to try using a different cable.  Some cables are "charge only" cables and will fool the phone into pulling more current than the USB port supports and so then the laptop goes "nope, you can't have that much power, so I'm turning you off".

That is what is AWESOME about USB-C it's the first USB where charging devices was baked into the standard from the beginning.